# Picking category from one dropdownlist to show sub categories in another dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, code-behind

Im trying to make a dropdownlist control another via C#.
My plan is, that the first DropDownList shows categories such as "Size" "Gender" "Model" and when you pick one of those, a new DropDownList shall appear with new sub categories for the former chosen category.

For example, if I pick "Size" a new DropDownList shal appear, with the option to choose from a number of sizes.

Im getting an error, while testing which sounds like this: Make sure your method arguments are in right format.

Here is what my code looks like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using ContactTableAdapters;

public partial class Test : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void ddlTwo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ddlTwo.Items.Clear();
        if (ddlThree.SelectedValue != "0")
        {
            Contact.CategoriesDataTable table;
            ddlTwo.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
            ddlTwo.Items.Add(new ListItem("Choose", "0"));
            CategoriesTableAdapter subM = new CategoriesTableAdapter();
            int CategoryID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlThree.SelectedValue); //This is where I get the error
            table = subM.GetCategoryByCategoryID(CategoryID);
            foreach (Contact.CategoriesRow row in table)
            {


                string text = row.Category;
                string value = row.CategoryID.ToString();
                ddlTwo.Items.Add(new ListItem(text, value));

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me, what I might have done wrong?

Comment: Please debug and see what ddlThree.SelectedValue actually is.  My guess is null...

Comment: "Input string was not in correct format" it says.

Comment: That is the value of the exception message, correct?  I need to know what the value of ddlThree.SelectedValue) is

Comment: It's probably an empty string. Therefor it can't parse it to an int. Are you sure ddlThree.SelectedValue has items and if so, one selected? I doubt it

Comment: The value from ddlTwo should be either "Size" "Gender" "Model" and when you pick one of those, the value should selected in ddlTwo is opening up for ddlThree, which should contain the value Sizes, Men/women" or "Models" - What that what you ment?

Comment: I think you have ddlTwo and ddlThree confused in your code.  You are responding to index changed on ddlTwo, so why are you getting the value from ddlThree?  I think you want to swap all ddlTwo in that block with ddlThree, and vice versa

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're returning a value that cannot be converted to an integer.

What you could do is create an Enum that could reference your worded value :

```
int CategoryID = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Category), (ddlThree.SelectedValue));
```

And your Enum would look like this :

```
enum Category
{
Size= 1,
Gender = 2,
Value = 3
}
```

Comment: I have absolutely no clue what an enum is!

Comment: Kasper, an enumeration (or enum for short) is a distinguished object type that allows you to store specialized constant values. In your case here, we're using a type of "Catergory" that has both a custom string and integer value. Instead of hard coding a conversion (such as Convert.ToInt32), we can use either of the native enum functions of Enum.GetValues to return the integers, or Enum.GetNames to return the strings. Hopefully this explains the use of this type.

Answer (score 0):

If you are actually responding to an event on ddlTwo, then use this:

```
protected void ddlTwo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ddlThree.Items.Clear();
        if (ddlTwo.SelectedValue != "0")
        {
            Contact.CategoriesDataTable table;
            ddlThree.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
            ddlThree.Items.Add(new ListItem("Choose", "0"));
            CategoriesTableAdapter subM = new CategoriesTableAdapter();
            int CategoryID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlTwo.SelectedValue); //This is where I get the error
            table = subM.GetCategoryByCategoryID(CategoryID);
            foreach (Contact.CategoriesRow row in table)
            {


                string text = row.Category;
                string value = row.CategoryID.ToString();
                ddlThree.Items.Add(new ListItem(text, value));

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thats not working a 100% because, when I choose either "Gender" "Size" or "Model" in ddlTwo, the same appears in ddlThree?

Comment: Then subM.GetCategoryByCategoryID(CategoryID); is likely not the method that you want to use to populate the drop down list.